# How to position elements around div dynamically?

Tags: html, css

I've created a button that switches the position of a div - it's working fine - but i don't want to set a specific values to the right, top, bottom, and left properties... i want them to align to their relative div in some way like float...

So here - all these properties shouldn't be... i think the direction is using Flexbox.... but i'm not too strong working with it.....

```
.top {
  top: -50px; 
}

.bottom {
  bottom: -50px;
}

.left {
  left: -200px;
}

.right {
  right: 260px;
}
```

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {

  var labels = $('.labels');
  $(labels).attr('class', 'labels');
  $(labels).addClass($(this).val());

})
```

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.labels {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.top {
  top: -50px;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: -50px;
}

.left {
  left: -200px;
}

.right {
  right: 260px;
}

.tabs-cont {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <select>
      <option value="top">top</option>
      <option value="bottom">bottom</option>
      <option value="left">left</option>
      <option value="right">right</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="labels">
      labels
    </div>

    <div class="tabs-cont">
      tabs cont
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the blue box to be inside the orange one?

Comment: Thanks - Just got it :)

Answer (score 1):

got it

```js
$('select').on('change', function(){

var labels = $('.labels');
var container = $('.tabs-wrapper');
var this_val = $(this).val();
console.log(this_val);
if(this_val =='top' || this_val =='bottom' ){
 
 $('.tabs-wrapper').attr('class', 'tabs-wrapper');
 $('.tabs-wrapper').addClass('display-column-mode');
}

if(this_val =='right' || this_val =='left' ){
 
 $('.tabs-wrapper').attr('class', 'tabs-wrapper');
 $('.tabs-wrapper').addClass('display-row-mode');
}

$(labels).attr('class', 'labels');
$(labels).addClass($(this).val());

})
```

```css
.tabs-wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.display-column-mode {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.display-row-mode {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.labels {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin-top: auto;
  
}

.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  order: 2;
}

.left {
  
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin-left: auto;
  
}

.right {
 
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin-right: auto;
  order: 2;
}

.tabs-cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <select>
  <option >select</option>
<option value="top">top</option>
<option value="bottom">bottom</option>
<option value="left">left</option>
<option value="right">right</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="tabs-wrapper">

  <div class="labels">
    labels
  </div>

  <div class="tabs-cont">
    tabs cont
  </div>
</div>
```